# Interference between Google API v3, OpenLayers 2.12 and graticule (lon/lat) lines

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

When I have Google Maps API V3 loaded in Openlayers 2.12 with graticule lines displayed, the graticules cover up the copyright information from google. Is there a way to have them stop at the Google copyright information so it doesn't look so cluttered?

Comment: Please write an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the opacity of the google icon to be more opaque and then the graticules didn't look so cluttered.

Something like this worked for me:

```
.olLayerGoogleCopyright{
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0px, rgba(153, 179, 204, 0.9) 26px);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0px, rgba(204,213,229, 0.9) 26px);
color:#686868;
}
```